# How to extend mysql functions into my own db class?

Tags: php, mysql, class, inheritance, extends

I have my own db class which has some purpose built functions that I am using.

I would like to also include all the standard mysql functions within that class so I can use encapsulation effectively. Rather than process data in an object and then process it using some external functions to that class object.

I would like all the common functions e.g.

> mysql_num_rows(), mysql_fetch_object(), mysql_fetch_assoc()

So the result would be:

e.g.

```
$rows = $db->mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Instead of doing

```
$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

I am assuming the standard mysql functions belong to a class in PHP somewhere. However I could not find documentation about that.

So it would be awesome if you could point me in the right direction for doing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the "standard" MySQL functions you are referring to are to be deprecated in a future PHP release (Taken from http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php, emphasis mine):

> It is recommended to use either the mysqli or PDO_MySQL extensions. **It
>   is not recommended to use the old mysql extension for new development.**

Even the mysqli_* functions are just that - functions - that are part of the PHP core but do not belong to any class. If you are looking to take an object-oriented approach, PDO_MySQL is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks this is good as with my db class I can provide a layer of abstraction from my main system code so that when this does get deprecated I can easily switch to mysqli or PDO.

Answer (score 1):

umm.. how about creating functions by the same name in your class and then call the standard MySQL functions from it. For example, something like:

```
class Db {
    function mysql_num_rows($result) {
        return mysql_num_rows($result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Write standard functions inside your functions and use them

```
      function yourFunction(){
      //standardFuncton
      }
```